# How to resolve issue "Your Ruby version is 3.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6" in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**While creating ReactNative Project I am getting this error :-

error Your Ruby version is 3.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6

to create a project**

Answer (score 1):

If you have the correct ruby version already installed and the are able to to create the project. You can try to to run `npx pod-install`.

If not you can use rbenv(or any ruby version manager) to download the correct version. Once you have installed, set v2.7.6 in the terminal to be the version to use.

rbenv: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv